implementing a custom ISlangFileSystem
in the newest version of the Vulkan SDK, they've included support for Slang shader language. I am trying to use this compiler programmatically from C++ code with a custom filesystem implementation (so I can track includes and recompile shaders at runtime).
    struct FileSystem : ISlangFileSystem {
        virtual SlangResult loadFile(char const* path, ISlangBlob** outBlob) override {
        }
    };
    
    struct SlangCompiler {
        slang::IGlobalSession* session = nullptr;
        slang::ICompileRequest* request = nullptr;
        FileSystem file_system;
    
        SlangCompiler() {
            SlangResult result;
            result = slang::createGlobalSession(&session);
            result = session->createCompileRequest(&request);           
            request->setFileSystem(&file_system);
        }
    
        ~SlangCompiler() {
            request->release();
            session->release();
            request = nullptr;
            session = nullptr;
        }
    };

I am getting the following errors (shortened for brevity)
error C2259: '`anonymous-namespace'::FileSystem': cannot instantiate abstract class
SlangResult ISlangUnknown::queryInterface(const SlangUUID &,void **)': is abstract
uint32_t ISlangUnknown::addRef(void)': is abstract
uint32_t ISlangUnknown::release(void)': is abstract
void *ISlangCastable::castAs(const SlangUUID &)': is abstract

I have found these macros which implement those functions but don't know how to use them. (in slang/slang-com-helper.h)
SLANG_REF_OBJECT_IUNKNOWN_QUERY_INTERFACE;
SLANG_REF_OBJECT_IUNKNOWN_ADD_REF;
SLANG_REF_OBJECT_IUNKNOWN_RELEASE;

And I have no idea how to implement the castAs function. Does anyone know a way I can get all the includes (recursively) used by a given slang shader?
